# Checking to see if an ID exists inside of a table using SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, select, sql-server-2008-r2

I am having a little trouble with a select statement in SQL Server 2008. I am building a ticket sale application web site and I need to make sure tickets that have already been sold can't be searched. Here is my SQL stored procedure:

```
    spGetSeatBySection
    @SectionID int
    AS
    SELECT
    [SeatID],
    [SectionID],
    [SeatName],
    [SeatPrice],
    [SeatDesc],
    [SeatIsActive],
  FROM [myDataBase].[dbo].[Seats]
  WHERE SectionID = @SectionID 
  AND SeatIsActive = 1 
  AND **IF EXISTS CLAUSE**;
```

I have tried a couple of the other methods that have been posted here like the if exists('table_name, 'column_name'). Is there another way of checking this without redesigning my `SELECT` statement?

Comment: Assuming these seats are stored sowhere that you can query to them you would use something like this:
WHERE EXISTS ( subquery )

Comment: Doesn't SeatIsActive designated that it has not been sold?

Comment: @ ron tornambe for any reason we need to disable a section or specific seat, I can't have them showing up in my search.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that with **[EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188336%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)**:

```
    SELECT
    [SeatID],
    [SectionID],
    [SeatName],
    [SeatPrice],
    [SeatDesc],
    [SeatIsActive],
  FROM [myDataBase].[dbo].[Seats]
  WHERE SectionID = @SectionID 
  AND SeatIsActive = 1 
  AND EXISTS (SELECT o.SeatID 
              FROM OrderItems o
              WHERE o.SeatID = [Seats].SeatID )
```

You probably can do and this:

```
     SELECT
    s.[SeatID],
    s.[SectionID],
    s.[SeatName],
    s.[SeatPrice],
    s.[SeatDesc],
    s.[SeatIsActive],
  FROM [myDataBase].[dbo].[Seats] s
       INNER JOIN OrderItems o ON o.SeatID = s.SeatID 
  WHERE s.SectionID = @SectionID 
  AND s.SeatIsActive = 1
```

Comment: That is what I was looking for, but the only problem is I'm referencing a table called OrderItems and I need to have the WHERE clause say SeatID = SeatID (although I don't pass in the SeatID). Is there any way of referencing Seat ID without declaring it as a scalar variable?                                                   WHERE SectionID = SectionID AND SeatIsActive = 1

AND EXISTS (SELECT SeatID 
              FROM OrderItems 
              WHERE SeatID = SeatID );